# Не обновляется horizontalSpacer на horizontalLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4

Я вывожу значение ширины `horizontalSpacer`, потом добавляю виджет в `horizontalLayout`, потом вывожу значение ширины `horizontalSpacer`. Значение ширины `horizontalSpacer` должно стать меньше, но оно не обновляется. Как сделать, чтобы обновлялось?`

```
void SearchForm::on_pushButton_10_clicked()
{
  std::cout <<  ui->horizontalSpacer->geometry().width()
            << std::endl;
  QPushButton* PB = new QPushButton;
  ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(PB);
  std::cout << ui->horizontalSpacer->geometry().width()
            << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: А зачем? При дефолтном sizeType=Expanding она ни на что не влияет

Comment: Я все sizeType перепробовал . ничего не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересующее нас изменение размера не явное, а является следствием добавления нового виджета и обрабатываются при отрисовке. Соответственно до этого размеры будут неизменны и изменятся, когда QLayout проанализирует требуемые размеры дочерних виджетов.

Таким образом для данной функции происходит следующее:

1. Выводится значение ширины
2. Создается кнопка
3. Выводится ширина
4. выход из функции
5. цикл обработки событий
6. вызов перерисовки

   1. изменение ширины
   2. отрисовка

Для получения размера в той же функции необходимо дополнительно вызвать перерисовку перед получением нового размера. Для этого используется функция QApplication::processEvents(), которая позволяет циклу обработчика сообщений обработать новые сигналы, среди которых находится и запрос на обновление окна.

```
void SearchForm::on_pushButton_10_clicked()
{
  std::cout <<  ui->horizontalSpacer->geometry().width()
        << std::endl;
  QPushButton* PB = new QPushButton;
  ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(PB);
  QApplication::instance()->processEvents();
  std::cout << ui->horizontalSpacer->geometry().width()
        << std::endl;

}
```